# Semantic UI React weird position of modal

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm trying to implement Modal from Semantic UI React. I don't know why, but in Semantic docs modal appears right in the center. Then I implemented this in my SPA, the modal appears full size on the left. How it can be solved?

[image: Here is the picture]

Answer (score 5):

I just found the problem, that on .ui.modal there is an option: `position: absolute`. You just need to change to `position: relative`